# React Native - How to make the text entered within the TextInput remains same, even though i am moving to next page?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a multi step form. It has 4 steps. I want the text entered in the step 1 to be same, even though I come back from step 2. How can I achieve that?

Comment: can you share what you did so far? code snippet ? please follow stackoverflow question guidelines How to Ask? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you can use regular components instead of having different routes for each step, you can store the input values in state variables on the parent component, and then pass the value, setValue to the step component as props

This way the value will only get reset if the parent component re-renders

Alternatively if you really need to define a different route for each step you can should opt for a context to share state between the different steps